# Cannot capture single quote string in Python from Perl

Tags: python, perl

I have a Perl script from which I am calling a Python script.

I am using:

```
system "python script.py '".$var1."' '".$var2."' '".$var3."' '".$var4."' '".$var5."'";
```

Where, `$var1 = "'Nostoc azollae' 0708"`, which has single quotes in the string.

In the `script.py` script, I am using:

```
var1 = sys.argv[1]
```

And if I print `var1`, it only prints: `Nostoc` and the rest is not printed, rest is working fine.

So, clearly the Python script is not receiving the string with the `'` included.

What can be a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid shell invocation when using `system()` by using separate parameters instead of joining them all together,

```
system("python", "script.py", $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);
```